# XML namespace for custom thymeleaf tags

Tags: xml, namespaces, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I add some custom thymeleaf's dialects and processors to my spring-boot project, in the packages: org.store.custom.thymeleaf.dialect and org.store.custom.thymeleaf.processor. In my html page, I configure the namespace in this way:

```
<html
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
  xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3"
  xmlns:form="http://form"
  xmlns:field="http://field">
```

which it's not working. What should be the right value for xmlns:form and xmlns:field to make the tags based on them work?

**UPDATE**

the thymeleaf configuration is this:

```
@Configuration
public class Thymeleaf {
  @Bean
  public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
    SpringTemplateEngine engine  =  new SpringTemplateEngine();

    final Set<IDialect> dialects = new HashSet<IDialect>();
    dialects.add( new SpringSecurityDialect() );
    dialects.add( new FormDialect() );
    dialects.add( new FieldDialect() );
    engine.setDialects( dialects );

    return engine;
  }
}
```

Comment: I am no an expert and I don't know the right answer but I leave it empty (`xmlns:form=""`) and it works. Perhaps your problem is with the configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After all, the problem isn't really with the namespace, but with my thymeleaf configuration. It works when I change the class Thymeleaf.java to this:

```
@Configuration
public class Thymeleaf {
  @Autowired
  private FormDialect formDialect;

  @Autowired
  private FieldDialect fieldDialect;

  @Bean
  public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
    SpringTemplateEngine engine  =  new SpringTemplateEngine();

    final Set<IDialect> dialects = new HashSet<IDialect>();
    dialects.add( new SpringSecurityDialect() );
    dialects.add( formDialect );
    dialects.add( fieldDialect );
    engine.setDialects( dialects );

    return engine;
  }

  @Bean
  public FormDialect formDialect() {
    return new FormDialect();
  }

  @Bean
  public FieldDialect fieldDialect() {
    return new FieldDialect();
  }
}
```